# phpmyadmin - Forbidden - You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, centos

I'm aware this has been asked many times before but all of the answers seem the same and none of them work for me.

I want to access the phpmyadmin GUI from something other than the localhost.

I'm getting the error "Forbidden - You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server." in the browser.

I'm using CentOS7, Apache 2.4.6 and phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.10-1.el7.

I've tried this:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
  Order Allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
  Order Allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Most people seem to suggest I can just do:

```
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    # Apache 2.4
    <RequireAny>
        Require all granted
    </RequireAny>
</IfModule>
```

Or:

```
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    # Apache 2.4
    <RequireAny>
        Require ip 192.168.1.6
    </RequireAny>
</IfModule>
```

But none of that works.

This is the current state:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 192.168.1.6
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Allow,Deny
     Allow from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Still getting:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.

EDIT-

Just as additional information, I have disabled SELinux and made sure permissions on /usr/share/phpMyAdmin are correct.

EDIT AGAIN-

I've now tried this...

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Which is surely as basic as you can get and yet I still get the error?

Answer (score 3):

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
         Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Allow,Deny
     Allow from All
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: "Require all granted" was the key

Answer (score 1):

Got this working eventually. There were a few problems at once, which was getting in the way of troubleshooting the main problem...

First, edit phpMyAdmin.conf...

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
         Require ip 192.168.1.6
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

OR

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
         Require all granted
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

You also need to make sure that/usr/share/phpMyAdmin is not only readable but also executable for the Apache user. I just recursively chmodded it to 777.

You also need to add the following to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

Check /var/log/httpd/error_log to see what your particular error is at each step.